# API error:191 in appmobi facebook integration HTML5 mobile web app

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, html5boilerplate, appmobi

I am trying to integrate facebook in my web application where the user can sign in using the facebook id and password but above I can't sign in to the web app -  I am frequently getting the following error:

> API Error Code: 191 API
>
> Error Description: The specified URL is not owned by the application
>
> Error Message: Invalid redirect_uri: Given
> URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.

And after we continue a facebook login page comes which directs us to the user's facebook account. Someone please suggest me how to do this?
I have tried the appmobifacebooktemplate and many samples
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/client-side/
http://thinkdiff.net/facebook/new-javascript-sdk-oauth-2-0-based-fbconnect-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the problem is that the URL that the application asks Facebook to redirect to is not sitting well with the new Facebook API.  The sample Facebook application and web pages on the appMobi site are well over a year old.  There is probably a bug with that.

A new Facebook integration API is due to be released by appMobi soon.  Perhaps that could solve the problem?